# Testing if a geometric series converges by taking limit to infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If the limit as n approaches infinity of a geometric series is not zero, then that means the series **diverges**.  This makes intuitive sense to me, because it is an infinite series and we keep adding nonzero terms, it will go to infinity.

However, if the limit as n approaches infinity **does** equal zero, series that is not enough information to tell whether the series converges or diverges.

I would think that if the limit as n approaches infinity is zero, and the series is a continuous function, then the series would converge to some real number.  Why is this not the case? The only counter-example I can think of is a series like: a^n = { (-1)^n },
but that is not a continuous function.

Comment: Convergence of infinite series has nothing to do with continuity; sequences are functions defined on the natural numbers, and any such function is continuous since the natural numbers form a discrete set.  The fact that we often consider sequences defined by formulas like $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$ which happen to make sense for all real values of $n$ is a red herring, and in particular the continuity of the functions determined by such formulas is largely irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0$ but $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ does not converge. The associated function $\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous from $[1, \infty)$.

Also a geometric series is the series associated with the sequence $a_n = pr^n$ for some $r$ and $p$. Geometric series converges if $|r| < 1$.

Comment: So if |r| > 1 it automatically diverges?

Comment: Yes. If $|r| \geq 1$, then $\lim_{n \rightarrow 0} pr^n \neq 0$.